# JavaScript requiring libraries

Tags: javascript, require

I'm quite new to the world of JavaScript (specially when it comes to libraries). Quite a few of them tell you to use `require('libName')` as a way to integrate the library on your web page/application. Could someone explain to me how exactly that works and how to implement this? Cause by default require() doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript in the browser doesn't have a `require` function, this functionality is provided by external libraries following the two most popular specs: [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) and [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). Take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) that plays nice with both patterns.

JavaScript on the server (NodeJS), uses CommonJS spec by default.

Comment: RequireJS has nothing in common with require('sdfs') Adonis is asking about, actually it's name is very confusing, it should be called AMDJS. require('package') is commonJS style, that can be easily be used in browser with tools like Webmake or Browserify

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very lightweight require:

```
var require = function(src, success, failure){
    !function(source, success_cb, failure_cb){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = source;
            script.onload = success_cb || function(e){};
            script.onerror = failure_cb || function(e){};
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    }(src, success, failure);
}

require('js/jquery.js', function(){
    console.log('jQuery is ready to use');
}, function(){
    console.log("Something went wrong loading this script");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Require is either a hand-made function which would be written yourself, or it is a part of a library which you would load before ANY other JS on the page.

For example, RequireJS is a library which deals in only dependency-loading (and namespacing, if need be).

You can make your own pretty simply, by using an `onload` event from the script tag you programmatically insert onto the page (or `onreadystatechange` for old versions of IE), with a couple of fallbacks depending on just how many super-old browsers you want to support.

By learning patterns for "Promises", you can also get into requiring dependencies right in the middle of your modules.

Again, different libraries support this in different ways.